# C# logging "thread" context

Tags: c#, logging

I'm trying to log data but I would like to have a way to "group" the logs in order to view the code that is being called for a specific instance\user. For example, if I have multiple classes and methods:

```
DateTime  UniqueId  Method  Class  Data
{date}    {111}     M1      C1     Input = {...}
{date}    {999}     M1      C1     Input = {...}
{date}    {999}     M2      C2     Input = {...}
{date}    {111}     M2      C2     Input = {...}
```

The most important aspect is the uniqueId. If I have 100's of rows, and know that a user with uniqueId = 111 had an issue, I want to filter logs only for UniqueId = 111. In other words, I want to add a unique context of a UniqueId, or say a threadId for each call.

Thanks

Comment: You have not mentioned what logging framework you are using but all of them have feature to log threadID. You can track down the entire flow if logs if you have the threadID

Answer (score 0):

If this is a proprietary logging framework that you are implementing then Check .NET "Reflection" library to find methods that help you with CallerMemberName, CurrentThreadContext etc. Properties.

If this is a functionality in a bigger system, then why re-invent the wheel. Go for established Logging frameworks like: NLog or Log4Net etc.

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying that Log4Net will provide me a unique context id for each thread that I can log and then group by in a query to see all the logs for a particular thread?In other words, if I have a service which is called by 2 consumers, and the service goes through the same flow, method1, 2 and 3. But since multiple calls can be made at the same time, the methods will log the data but I will not know for which consumer it is logged for. I would like to include a unique ID for each consumer's log so that I can see the data and all related logs specifically for that consumer.

Comment: Just to clarify one thing. I'm talking about a uniqueue ID, nothing to do with the thread. Consumer1 comes in, gets ID123 and this ID is logged for every subsequent log. Meanwhile, consumer2 comes in and receives ID999, and now this ID is always logged for their instance.

Comment: This Consumer UniqueId is your application level concept. So Logging framework will/cannot assign that. But nothing stops you from maintaining & printing the UniqueId yourself in relevant ILog.Info() or Error() calls.

Comment: FYI - you can extend Log4Net (& others) for your specific use by defining a custom appender and implement your logic in it.

Comment: Yes, I could extend any logging framework, but that means I would need to use dependency injection in all my calls to pass the unique id along all calls which is what I'm trying to avoid.